# Azure Mobile Services: how to inject custom header into request?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services from within a Xamarin.iOS app.
My service expects a custom header to be sent from the client.

In order to send this, I created my own message handler which I derive from `NativeMessageHandler (part of ModernHttpClient):

`this.client = new MobileServiceClient (Constants.ApplicationURL, Constants.GatewayURL, new CustomMessageHandler ());`

To get my header in there, the handler looks like this:

```
public class CustomMessageHandler: NativeMessageHandler
{
        protected override Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
            request.Headers.Add ("customHeader", "headerValue");
            return base.SendAsync (request, cancellationToken);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the header doesn't seem to arrive at the server when my service is deployed to Azure. *It works when running it locally in VisualStudio*. If I put a breakpoint into my handler, it is hit; so the header really gets added.

Why would it work locally but not on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is: *D'oh!*

I enabled "Authentication" for my Azure App. Hence I would get a 401 for every request. It had nothing to do with my handler. Turned it off and it works like charm.